# How to prevent button to jump down in sm or xs screen?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so i have this bootstrap-form. and i'm trying to get the buttons to stay in place after the input field. It's fine in lg & md screen'n but in sm & xs the button jumps down below the input field. How can i prevent this from happening?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form class="form-inline well" id="usr_reg_in" name="usr_reg_out" method="post" action="php/usr_time_reg.php">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="reg_out">Tack för idag</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append">
                  <input id="reg_out" name="reg_out" class="form-control" placeholder="Anst. nr" type="text">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Ut</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The class `.form-control` has the default values of `display: block;`
and `width: 100%;` you will have to override those values in order to have the button remain on the same line as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bootstrap will make all input 100% width on screens less than 768px, another option would be to use an `input-group` like this..

```
             <div class="input-group"> 
                  <input id="reg_out" name="reg_out" class="form-control" placeholder="Anst. nr" type="text">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Ut</button>
                  </span>
             </div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/tU94xwqnZU